# Android webview returns navigator.online true

Tags: android, webview, chromium

Within the Android Webview I am rechecking every 10 seconds if navigator.onLine returns true to get new data or if false to continue use local data.

However, the Android WebView always returns true for the navigator.onLine.
Within the Chrome browser (on the phone) the same website works properly and shows the right status (true/false) depending on the connection.

I debugged it with the logcat and also remote chrome inspector. Within the remote chrome inspector I can switch the connection manually offline. Anyone the same problem or some idea to tackle that problem apart from using a network listener within java (the native app).

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    // check if new data is available
    checkDataUpdate();
  } else {
    // OFFLINE - Mode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after trying different approaches I figured out that I had one web property `webView.setNetworkAvailable(true);`

which was the main reason of navigator.onLine returns always true. Just find that you have the above code and comment out that. After that the webView will work just as chrome browser.

**From android doc:**

```
setNetworkAvailable
```

Added in API level 3

```
void setNetworkAvailable (boolean networkUp)
```

Informs WebView of the network state. This is used to set the JavaScript property window.navigator.isOnline and generates the online/offline event as specified in HTML5

Comment: not working in all cases but most of the time, thx, if someone else knows more sideeffects, let us now.